# The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python

The term 'virtualenv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: did you install module `virtualenv` ? Maybe it needs to use `/full/path/to/virtualenv`